# make a list with values from another list and element position from another one

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists, `list1` and `list2`; `list1` with some data values and `list2` with the "element position" where I want to store the values of `list1`.

I want to create another list, `list3` (with `len(list3) > len(list1)` and `len(list3) > len(list1)`), in which put the values of `list1` in the positions listed in `list2`.

For example:

```
list1 = [3, 5, 11]
list2 = [2, 6, 8]
```

And I want to obtain `list3 = [ , , 3, , , 5, , , 11, ,]`

The best would be to obtain "empty spaces" instead of zeros, but I am not sure it is possible.

I know it will possibly be solved by using list comprehension, but I am striving since a bit and in no way able to figure it out.

Comment: I think he closed it because you did not specify how to tell the length of `list3`.

Comment: Are you sure you want a list? Python lists don't have any way to add "empty spaces", but a dictionary doesn't need to have values for any keys that you don't want to add. `dict(zip(list2, list1))` may be exactly what you want.

Comment: I think he wants: `for index,num in enumerate(list2): list3[num]=list1[index]`

Comment: `list3 = [None] * max(list1)`

Comment: `for i,x in enumerate(list2): list3[x] = list2[i]`

Comment: Thanks all! Very helpful! What should I add to reopen the question? @merlin2011, why would one need the length of `list3`?

Comment: @Py-ser, I'm not sure if you can reopen the question unless 4 other people vote to reopen, or you flag it for another moderator to correct the close.

Comment: The reason why you need the length of `list3` is because your question makes it look like `list3` has elements beyond the largest index specified by `list2`, and it is not clear how much larger it should be.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand yet: as far as elements of `list2` do not point "outside" of `len(list3)`, it is safe. Right?

Comment: Py-ser, I think the confusion comes from your statement of "with length bigger than list1 and list2". Its unclear what you mean by this or why this is needed.

Comment: @Tommy, I see. I meant `len(list3) > len(list1)` and `len(list3) > len(list1)`. I thought it could be useful to know `list2` do not point till the last element. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Does `list3` already exist? There's no way to make a list with an unspecified length in Python. Before I'd consider voting to reopen this question, you'll need to be a lot more clear about what you're trying to do and what expect your `list3` to be capable of. Are you going to iterate over the values? Add other values into the "empty spaces"? Both? As it stands, the question is nonsensical.

Comment: I have initialized the `list3 = [0]*length_I_want`, but I guess this depends on if I can or not have "empty" elements (as the OP above stated, in the case of a dictionary this is not necessary). As for what I want to do with `list3`, I want to stack some values for many cycles, each cycle having some values for different element positions. However, answers above are fine, but reopening the post is better of course!

Comment: Try this for a one-liner: `list3 = [(i in list2 and list1[list2.index(i)]) or None for i in range(LENGTH_YOU_WANT)]`. Code golf win!

Answer (score 0):

First, use [None](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) to indicate "empty value". So your goal is to obtain :

```
list1 = [3, 5, 11]
list2 = [2, 6, 8]
list3 = [None, None, 3, None, None, None, 5, None, 11]
```

So you should initialize list3 with None values for indices equal the maximum value contained by list2, then parse list2 and insert list1 values into list3 :

```
list3 = [None for x in range(max(list2)+1)]
for x in range(len(list2)):
    try:
        list3[list2[x]] = list1[x]
    except IndexError: # list1 may not have the same number of elements than list2.
        pass
```

At then end, you have :

```
>>> list3
[None, None, 3, None, None, None, 5, None, 11]
```

This solution works even if list1 does not contain the same number of elements than list2 and even if elements in list2 are not sorted.